# incrementing a value by one visual basics am stuck

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write a code that will increment a value by one after clicking a button in visual basic.these are the codes i have tried so far but i have not achieved my objective

**code 1**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   Dim votecount As Integer = Integer.Parse(showcountwinnie.Text)
   votecount += 1
   showcountwinnie.Text = votecount.ToString()
End Sub
```

**code two**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim votes As Integer
  votes = 0
  votes += 1
  votes = showcountwinnie.Text
End Sub
```

**code three**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   Dim votewinnie As Integer
   votewinnie = showcountwinnie.value
   votewinnie = votewinnie + 1
   showcountwinnie.value = votewinnie
End Sub
```

Comment: Option two should no compile, set `OPTION STRICT` to on. Option three is commented out. The first approach should work, so you should give us more background informations. Is it winforms or asp.net, **what means "not achieved my objective"**?

Comment: what is the first one not doing?

Comment: it is winforms not asp.net.

Comment: i cant increment the figure by one

Answer (score 8):

Quick and dirty way:

```
        Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            showcountwinnie.Text = (Val(showcountwinnie.Text) + 1).ToString()
        End Sub
```

A more elegant way:

```
        Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Dim votecount As Integer
            If Integer.TryParse(txt_UTC.Text, votecount) Then
                votecount += 1
            Else
                ' whatever you want to do with votecount
                votecount = 0
            End If
            txt_UTC.Text = votecount.ToString()
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Not the most elegant solution but working:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim vote As Integer
    If showcountwinnie.Text <> "" Then
        vote = Val(showcountwinnie.Text)
    Else
        vote = 0
    End If

    vote += 1
    showcountwinnie.Text = vote
End Sub
```

Comment: As a comment: Integer.Parse will blow up in your face if the text is not a number. Better user Integer.Tryparse - it is slightly more complicated but has a better control flow-

Comment: @ChristianSauer or he may use val() function. It will return 0, if the passed argument is not a number.

Comment: True enough, that would make more sense.

Comment: Also you can check IsNumeric(a_text)   but sometimes it says yes, but it is a special case of a float, so still use TryParse, or put a CInt in a Try..Catch block

Comment: `Val` is an old VB6 method which is supported in VB.NET, but mainly just for backwards compatibility.  It would be better to use `Integer.Parse` or `Integer.TryParse`.

Answer (score 1):

Using above suggested code, I'm posting the code which really worked for me with minor change

```
Private Sub txtQuantity_Click()
    Dim vote As Integer
    If txtQuantity.Text <> "" Then
        vote = Val(txtQuantity.Text)
    Else
        vote = 0
    End If

    vote = vote + 1
    txtQuantity.Text = vote

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The Code 1 seems to be correct. Just try keeping a breakpoint at line 1 and check whether the code lines are getting executed while you click on the button

Comment: Problem is when the textbox/label is empty the code will break.

Comment: Yes you are right. I din think that also I din see your answer . We both posted together I guess. Anyways thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Static votecount As Integer = 0
    votecount += 1
    showcountwinnie.Text = votecount.ToString()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
showcountwinnie.Text = showcountwinnie.text + 1
```

This method is using itself to +1 every click

Answer (score -1):

Kinda late but ur code 1 wont work the Parse method needs two arguments.

In code two you are meant to assign the things the other way around from the look of things like *showcountwinnie.Text = votes* 
 What is this showcountwinnie anyway? a textbox? a label?